# Paste audio and video

Tags: video, audio

I have recorded a video with a digital camera, and separately used an audio recorder with a good microphone to get better sound (I could not directly connect the microphone to the camera).

What software (Linux preferred but Windows possible) could replace the audio track from what the camera has recorded with the better one, and autodetect timeshift with some correlation algorithm?

Thank you,

Benoit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I prefer kdenlive for video editing.  In kdenlive you have to split the audio track from the video before you can replace it.  So the process is something like: import clip, split audio from video, delete audio track, import audio, make sure lengths match and offset is synced properly, export.  That's how I do it.  I had to cut up an audio track once to amplify sections or use an external audio editor to normalize the audio in a couple of instances.  Audio editing didn't work well for me in kdenlive, so i just used it to manipulate the whole track or cut out pieces of audio.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use a software like:

- http://heroinewarrior.com/cinelerra.php (Cinerella)
- http://www.kinodv.org/ (Kino)
- http://kdenlive.org/ (KDenlive)
- http://lives.sourceforge.net/ (LiVES)

Good luck

Comment: I had already tried with Cinelerra, but I did not succeed. Could you suggest a way to achieve it using that software? I hope that does not bother you, but it is worth 50 reputation :)

Comment: Honestly I use iMovie :-)  
I just know the other software but didn't use them What you have to do is saving the film without the sound on one file then the good sound on another file and mix them. I'm pretty sure you can also add in a project the two files and lower to zero the sound volume of the video.